# Magento 2 how to add loading lazy to image product?

Tags: magento2, catalog

I'm trying to add the tag , loading="lazy" to the template that I've found that prints the image, but it´s not working.

app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/web/template/product/image_with_borders.html

```
<span class="product-image-container" data-bind="style: {width: width + 'px'}">
    <span class="product-image-wrapper"  data-bind="style: {'padding-bottom': height/width*100 + '%'}">
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <img class="product-image-photo" data-bind="attr: {src: src, alt: alt, 'loading': 'lazy'}" />
    </span>
</span>
```

It's not changing anything.
Now I've found that list.phtml template prints the image like this

```
 $productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $image);
<?php echo $productImage->toHtml() ?>
```

But this is a block as far as I know, I just don't know where to find that .phtml block, or is it the one that I'm modifying?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any reason to pass this in as a `data-bind` attribute, since this is a static value. Try adding it as a regular HTML attribute?

```html
<img class="product-image-photo" loading="lazy" data-bind="attr: {src: src, alt: alt}" />
```

Comment: did not work either, even my <h1>Test</h1> is not visible

Comment: oh my bad, I've found that the actual template is this Magento_Catalog::product/image_with_borders.phtml, it's found on ImageFactory

Answer (score 0):

I've found the right template, it's here:
Magento_Catalog::product/image_with_borders.phtml

You can find it here Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageFactory

on create method:

```
$data = [
            'data' => [
                'template' => 'Magento_Catalog::product/image_with_borders.phtml',
                'image_url' => $imageAsset->getUrl(),
                'width' => $imageMiscParams['image_width'],
                'height' => $imageMiscParams['image_height'],
                'label' => $this->getLabel($product, $imageMiscParams['image_type']),
                'ratio' => $this->getRatio($imageMiscParams['image_width'], $imageMiscParams['image_height']),
                'custom_attributes' => $this->getStringCustomAttributes($attributes),
                'class' => $this->getClass($attributes),
                'product_id' => $product->getId()
            ],
        ];
```